# jQuery changing showText to a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about my javascript code.
I got this script from internet, but the problem is that it displays text, I want to make a div of it because I want it like a button instead.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  var maxheight=218;
  var showText = "Lees meer..";
  var hideText = "Inklappen";

  $('.leesmeer').each(function () {
    var text = $(this);
    if (text.height() > maxheight){
        text.css({ 'overflow': 'hidden','height': maxheight + 'px' });

        var link = $('<a href="#">' + showText + '</a>');
        var linkDiv = $('<div></div>');
        linkDiv.append(link);
        $(this).after(linkDiv);

        link.click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (text.height() > maxheight) {
              $(this).hktml(showText);
              text.css('height', maxheight + 'px');
          } else {
              $(this).html(hideText);
              text.css('height', 'auto');
          }
        });
    }       
  });
```

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: It would help if you posted the HTML. Even better if you made a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)!

Comment: There is no html to be shown, everything inside my '.leesmeer' class adapts to the script.

But here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qSvb2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fun i tried changing the code into a jquery plugin, which you could find here, and which simplifies the ready function quite a lot :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/SA744/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.leesmeer').readMore({});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use input tag with type="button" and value="something " it works

```
var link = $('<input type="button" value=' + showText + '/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the div tag to the text :

```
var showText = "<div class='more-less'>Read More..</div>";
var hideText = "<div class='more-less'>Read Less</div>";
```

#### JSFiddle

Comment: Didn't knew it was that easy, thanks alot!
Now I see what I did wrong, I used " instead of '.

Comment: @MBouwman Yes, you can still use `"` by escaping it with a backslash : `" this is \"cool\" text "`